# What's the geometry of a puzzle key called?

Tags: geometry, puzzle

Is there a name for the geometry of a classic puzzle key?

It's not an ellipse, neither a circle, ...

[image]

Comment: Do you want to make a puzzle or a puzzle piece with software? Or is it just curiosity? If the former, you could try with Bezier curves.

Comment: This is not really a math question. The curve will be whatever shape the blades cutting the puzzle are. How to name that detail of the piece is the matter of English usage -- and it was discussed on English.SE site, [What do you call the interconnecting bits of a puzzle piece in English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/47667)

Comment: A nephroid? An elliptic curve?

Comment: I know that you would implement this with a Bézier curve in a programmatic context. But a Bézier curve is (imho) not a geometry. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat Thank you! But your linked question says nothing about the name of the geometry. PS: Here in Switzerland I think we call these things "key" and "lock" (freely translated).